# Multibranch pipelines not working if it's created by job DSL

Tags: jenkins

i have a job DSL job script that creates folders for each pipeline and inside each folder it creates the relative multibranch pipeline. after suffering a bit with syntax I managed to to create that script but the issue is when the multibranch pipeline is created by DSL job, it doesn't scan nor build anything, however creating manually mulitbranch pipeline with exact  configuration works. any idea why is that?

i tried to restart jenkins but still only works if multibranch pipeline is created manually

here's the code script:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def map = [
    'a': 'so',
    'b': 'no',
    'c': 'one',
    'd': 'told',
    'e': 'life',
    'f': 'was',
    'g': 'gonna',
    'h': 'be',
    'i': 'this',
    'j': 'way',
    'k': 'your',
    'l': 'love',
    'm': 'is joke',
    'n': 'you broke',
    'o': 'your love life`s DOA',
    'p': 'it`s like you always stuck in the second gear when',
    'q': 'it hasn`t been your day',
    'r': 'your week, your month',
    's': 'or even your year',
]

map.each { service, service_webhook_token ->
    def folderPath = "${Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(service)}"
    if (folderPath != null) {
        folder("${service}") {
            displayName("${service}")
            description("This is a folder for service ${service}")
        }

        def environments = ["${service}/DEV", "${service}/STG", "${service}/TST"]

        for (environment in environments) {
            if (!Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(environment)) {
                multibranchPipelineJob("${environment}") {
                    branchSources {
                        branchSource {
                            source {
                                git {
                                    id("${service}-${environment}")
                                    credentialsId("friends")
                                    remote("link/${service}.git")
                                    traits {
                                        headRegexFilter {
                                            if (environment.contains('DEV')) {
                                                regex("develop")
                                            } else if (environment.contains('STG')) {
                                                regex("staging")
                                            } else if (environment.contains('TST')) {
                                                regex("tst")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    factory {
                        templateBranchProjectFactory {
                            filterBranches(true)
                        }
                    }
                    orphanedItemStrategy {
                        discardOldItems {
                            numToKeep(1)
                        }
                    }
                    triggers {
                        computedFolderWebHookTrigger {
                            token("${service_webhook_token}") // Using the token associated with the service
                        }
                    }
                    properties {
                        templateConfigFolderProperty {
                            tier {
                                configurationProvider {
                                    scmPipelineConfigurationProvider {
                                        scm {
                                            gitSCM {
                                                browser { "" }
                                                branches {
                                                    branchSpec {
                                                        name("*/main")
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                gitTool("")
                                                userRemoteConfigs {
                                                    userRemoteConfig {
                                                        name('repo')
                                                        refspec('+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/@{remote}/*')
                                                        url("link/${service}-config.git")
                                                        credentialsId("friends")
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println "Job ${environment} already exists. Skipping creation."
            }
        }
    } else {
        println "Folder ${service} already exists. Skipping creation."
    }
}
```